# Rails 3 render layout except for root_url

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, layout

I want to have a different layout for the home page (root_url) than the other pages in my web app. I would like to be able to use `<%= render 'layouts/pages' %>` for pages that are not the home page. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Majority

The best way to do this is to name the layout for the majority of your app `layouts/application` - this way, Rails will automatically assume this layout for that majority without you needing to do anything else.

### Home

For your home page, you can add this line to the bottom of your controller action:

```
render :layout => "home"
```

This will tell Rails not to use `application`, but instead to point to your home/root page's layout, which in this case would be located at `layouts/home`.

Comment: OK that's working. So it just renders whatever is in `layouts/home`. How can I make it so it puts the content from `pages/home` into this layout? Cheers

Comment: Adding `<%= yield %>` to it displays what is it `pages/home`.